# How to calculate means by rows

Tags: r

I would like to know how to calculate the mean (C4) of two variables(C1 & C2) by the id row:

Example:

Given a sample data frame

```
    ID C1 C2 C3    C4      C5
     1  3  3  5    3       3.9
     2  2  7  4    4,5     3.9
     3  4  3  3    3,5     3.9
     4  4  4  6    4       3.9
     5  5  5  3    5       3.9
```

I tried:

```
data <- within(data,{ C4<- (mean(C1)+mean(C2))/2})
```

That gives only (C5) one value. I think I need something like:

```
data <- within(data,{ C4<- (mean(C1)+mean(C2))/2, by=list(ID)})
```

I would like to keep the within structure because I have to create several new variables as means for given variables using the same logic as stated above. 
And to make matters worse I have also to use na.rm=T in that command.

Comment: Have you tried `data$C4 <- rowMeans(data[, c("C1", "C2")])`?

Comment: I get the error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Huh? It worked perfectly fine for your provided data set. Maybe add `na.rm=T`? As in `rowMeans(data[, c("C1", "C2")], na.rm = T)`. Otherwise your problem is not reproducible

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I had troubles with the within structure

Comment: May I ask you whether this is working with whithin structure?       data <- within(data,{ C4<-rowMeans(data[, c("C1", "C2")]}). I just cant implement it.

Comment: `within(data, C4 <- rowMeans(cbind(C1, C2)))` Or `transform(data, C4 = rowMeans(cbind(C1, C2)))`

Comment: Btw, is every row is unique ID or you have duplicated IDs? Because you can also calculate row mean (or any other function) per ID

Answer (score 1):

Following simple code should also work: ddf$C6 = (ddf$C1+ddf$C2)/2
(can use C4 instead of C6)

```
ddf = structure(list(ID = 1:5, C1 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L), C2 = c(3L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 5L), C3 = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L), C4 = c("3", "4,5", 
"3,5", "4", "5"), C5 = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9)), .Names = c("ID", 
"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
> 
> 
ddf
  ID C1 C2 C3  C4  C5
1  1  3  3  5   3 3.9
2  2  2  7  4 4,5 3.9
3  3  4  3  3 3,5 3.9
4  4  4  4  6   4 3.9
5  5  5  5  3   5 3.9
> 
> 
ddf$C6 = (ddf$C1+ddf$C2)/2
ddf
  ID C1 C2 C3  C4  C5  C6
1  1  3  3  5   3 3.9 3.0
2  2  2  7  4 4,5 3.9 4.5
3  3  4  3  3 3,5 3.9 3.5
4  4  4  4  6   4 3.9 4.0
5  5  5  5  3   5 3.9 5.0
> 
>
```

or:

```
ddf$C6 = with(ddf, (C1+C2)/2)
```